# complex data.table subset and vectorised maniulation

Tags: r, data.table

Ok I have a complex function built using data.frames and in trying to speed it up I've turned to data.table. I'm totally new to this so I'm quite befuddled. Anyhow I've made a much much simpler toy example of what I want to do, but I cannot work out how to translate it into data.table format. Here is the example in data.frame form:

```
    rows <- 10
    data1 <- data.frame(   id =1:rows,
                    a = seq(0.2, 0.55, length.out = rows),
                  b = seq(0.35, 0.7, length.out = rows),
                  c = seq(0.4, 0.83, length.out = rows),
                  d = seq(0.6, 0.87, length.out = rows),
                  e = seq(0.7, 0.99, length.out = rows),
                  f = seq(0.52, 0.90, length.out = rows)             
    )
    DT1 <- data.table(data1) #for later

    data2 <- data.frame(   id =3:1,
                   a = rep(3, 3),
                   d = rep(2, 3),
                   f = rep(1, 3)
    )
    m.names <- c("a", "d", "f")

    data1[match(data2$id, data1$id),m.names] <- data1[match(data2$id, data1$id),m.names] + data2[match(data2$id, data1$id),m.names]
```

So note in the last step that I want perform addition between the pre-existing figures and the new data and its vectorised across several columns.

In a data.table format I've only gotten this far:

```
    DT1[id %in% data2$id, m.names, with=FALSE]
```

This selects the values I want to add to but after that I am lost. I would appreciate any help !

EDIT:

Ok I've figure out part of it - I can use the last line of code above to achieve the vectorised addition part using using data2 to store the added values as follows:

```
    data2[,m.names] <- data2[,m.names] + data.frame(DT1[id %in% data2$id, m.names, with=FALSE])
```

Even with 2.5million rows (in DT1) and 10,000 rows in data2 and 6 matching columns this only takes 0.004sec, but I still need to assign the new data2 to the appropriate dynamically assigned columns in data 1

Comment: You can do a simple binary join if you don't mind calling the column names manually, something like `setkey(setDT(data1), id) ; data1[data2, ":="(a = a + i.a,d = d + i.d,f = f + i.f)]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Your solution is much better and compact.

Comment: @akrun your solution is more general so I'd leave it there and let the OP decide

Comment: Thanks David , but doesn't work in my real data. I can't use a,d,f I need to use m.names[1] as the number of columns can vary - using m.names[] construct doesn't seem to work.. Second point is in the toy data the match version appears quicker (and in the real code I use fmatch)

Comment: Ok I've found a quick way to do the addition via vectorisation - see my edit - but I still need to pack the results back into data1 using the variable assigned column names ??

Comment: Ok actually I have solved it by first constructing an expression from the dynamic variable names and combining that with your code David.Thank you! This is very fast! `text <- NULL
for(i in length(m.names)){
    text <- paste0(text, m.names[i], " = ", m.names[i], " + i.", m.names[i], ", ")
}
expr <- parse(text = paste0("\":=\"(", substr(text, 1, nchar(text)-2), ")" ))
data1[data2, eval(expr), with=FALSE]
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to @David Arenburg for his suggestion. I've modified it slightly to arrive at the following for my preferred solution

```
    text <- NULL
    for(i in 1:length(m.names)){
        text <- paste0(text, m.names[i], " = ", m.names[i], " + i.", m.names[i], ", ")
    }
    expr <- parse(text = paste0("\":=\"(", substr(text, 1, nchar(text)-2), ")" ))

    res2 <- DT1[data2, eval(expr)]
```

Comment: I don't think you need a `for` loop here, `paste0` is vectorized.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way, using [devel version `data.table v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.5+
setDT(data1)        ## data1 is now a data.table

cols1 = c("a", "d", "f")
cols2 = paste0("i.", cols1)
setkey(data1, id)   ## setkey and prepare for join
data1[data2, (cols1) := mapply(`+`, mget(cols1), mget(cols2), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)]
#     id         a         b         c    d         e         f
#  1:  1 3.2000000 0.3500000 0.4000000 2.60 0.7000000 1.5200000
#  2:  2 3.2388889 0.3888889 0.4477778 2.63 0.7322222 1.5622222
#  3:  3 3.2777778 0.4277778 0.4955556 2.66 0.7644444 1.6044444
#  4:  4 0.3166667 0.4666667 0.5433333 0.69 0.7966667 0.6466667
#  5:  5 0.3555556 0.5055556 0.5911111 0.72 0.8288889 0.6888889
#  6:  6 0.3944444 0.5444444 0.6388889 0.75 0.8611111 0.7311111
#  7:  7 0.4333333 0.5833333 0.6866667 0.78 0.8933333 0.7733333
#  8:  8 0.4722222 0.6222222 0.7344444 0.81 0.9255556 0.8155556
#  9:  9 0.5111111 0.6611111 0.7822222 0.84 0.9577778 0.8577778
# 10: 10 0.5500000 0.7000000 0.8300000 0.87 0.9900000 0.9000000
```

The *join* of the form `x[i]` is performed on the key column `id`. For each row of *data2*'s `id` column, the corresponding matching rows in *data1* is found. For example, for `id = 2` from *data2*, the matching row is the 2nd row in *data1*.

Once we've all the matching rows, we evaluate the expression in `j`, which updates the *data1* columns provided in `col1` by adding the values from `mget(cols1)` and `mget(cols2)`.

`cols2` was generated with a `i.` prefix, which fetches the values from the *data.table i* -- here *data2*.

HTH

Comment: Looks nice but does it require the development version ? I'm trying it under v1.9.4 and its giving me the error: `Error: value for ‘a’ not found`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `set` in a `for` loop as this involves multiple columns.  Convert the second dataset to 'data.table' (DT2), set the key with the 'id' column, and join with 'data1'.  Create column index vectors for the 'm.names' column in the dataset ('indx1') and `i.` columns created after the join ('indx2').  Using a `for` loop, `set` the `NA` elements in 'm.names' columns to '0', and then sum the corresponding columns based on the 'indx1' and 'indx2'.

```
DT2 <- as.data.table(data2)
DTNew <- setkey(DT2, id)[data1]
indx1 <- match(m.names, names(DTNew))
indx2 <- grep('i\\.', names(DTNew))

for(k in seq_along(indx1)){
  set(DTNew, i=which(is.na(DTNew[[indx1[k]]])), j= indx1[k], value=0)
  set(DTNew, i=NULL, j= indx2[k], value = DTNew[[indx1[k]]]+
                                      DTNew[[indx2[k]]])
  }

 res <- DTNew[,2:4 := NULL]
 setnames(res, names(data1))
```

Checking with the modified 'data1'

```
  data1[match(data2$id, data1$id),m.names] <- data1[match(data2$id, 
       data1$id),m.names] + data2[match(data2$id, data1$id),m.names]
  all.equal(setDF(res), data1)
  #[1] TRUE
```

#### Benchmarks

```
On a 1e6 dataset, 

set.seed(24)
data1 <- cbind(id=1:1e6,as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1e6*10), ncol=10, 
         dimnames=list(NULL, letters[1:10])) ))
 set.seed(46)
 data2 <- data.frame(id= sample(1:1000, 100, replace=FALSE), 
             a= rnorm(100), d=rnorm(100), f= rnorm(100))
 m.names <- c("a", "d", "f")

 DT2 <- as.data.table(data2)
 system.time({
   DTNew <- setkey(DT2, id)[data1]
   indx1 <- match(m.names, names(DTNew))
   indx2 <- grep('i\\.', names(DTNew))

   for(k in seq_along(indx1)){
   set(DTNew, i=which(is.na(DTNew[[indx1[k]]])), j= indx1[k], value=0)
   set(DTNew, i=NULL, j= indx2[k], value = DTNew[[indx1[k]]]+
                                  DTNew[[indx2[k]]])
   }

  res <- DTNew[,2:4 := NULL]
  setnames(res, names(data1))
  })

 # user  system elapsed 
 # 0.082   0.005   0.086
```

Comment: I will have to take this on board line by line to get it - but off hand it strikes me that this has many steps and is likely slow ?

Comment: @user2498193 `set` is usually very fast for big datasets.  You can look at the examples in `?set` comparing different approaches.  Regarding the multiple steps, two steps are for creating the index, which doesn't have much influence on the speed. Binary join, `set` and then assigning the extra columns to NULL are fast.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now - comes about 40% faster than yours on the 1e6 dataset:
`system.time({
    DT1 <- data.table(data1)
    setkey(DT1, id) ; setkey(DT2, id)
    text <- NULL
    for(i in 1:length(m.names)){
        text <- paste0(text, m.names[i], " = ", m.names[i], " + i.", m.names[i], ", ")
    }
    expr <- parse(text = paste0("\":=\"(", substr(text, 1, nchar(text)-2), ")" ))
    
    res2 <- DT1[DT2, eval(expr)]
})`
But `identical(res, res2)` fails for some reason I can't easily spot

Comment: @user2498193 Thanks, anyway, this is another way of doing the same thing, though I would use `eval(parse` as a last resort.  The `identical` can fail if any of the attributes differ..

Comment: Why avoid `eval(parse)` ?

Comment: @user2498193  This link may give some ideas http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/20974-Why-is-eval-parse-bad